Errors with method overloading in a generic class
In the toy example below, I define a generic class Foo. I overload the class initializer, to impose a type dependency on the parameters:
import enum
import typing

class EValType(enum.Enum):
    STRING  = 1
    FLOAT = 4

T = typing.TypeVar("T", str, float)

class Foo(typing.Generic[T]):
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, val_type: typing.Literal[EValType.STRING], val: str) -> None:
        ...
    
    @typing.overload
    def __init__(self, val_type: typing.Literal[EValType.FLOAT], val: float) -> None:
        ...
    
    def __init__(self, val_type: EValType, val: T) -> None:
        self.val_type: EValType = val_type
        self.val: T = val
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Foo(EValType.STRING, "hello")
    b = Foo(EValType.FLOAT, 23)  
    c = Foo(EValType.STRING, 3.14)   # mypy should fail on that.

Running mypy on that code, I get:
test.py:19: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 1  [misc]
test.py:19: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2  [misc]
test.py:27: error: No overload variant of "Foo" matches argument types "EValType", "float"  [call-overload]
test.py:27: note: Possible overload variants:
test.py:27: note:     def [T in (str, float)] __init__(self, val_type: Literal[EValType.STRING], val: str) -> Foo[T]
test.py:27: note:     def [T in (str, float)] __init__(self, val_type: Literal[EValType.FLOAT], val: float) -> Foo[T]

mypy correctly reports an issue on the very last line. However, the first errors elude me.
If I remove the overloads, mypy is happy, but I obviously loose the type dependency on the __init__ parameters.

What's the purpose of EValType? The value of val carries enough information to infer a legal value for val_type, so there shouldn't be any need for val_type as an parameter at all.

That's correct. I'm working with this oversimplified code sample, to try and understand the problem.

If you remove the type hints from the implementation, the error goes away while still allowing the assignment to c to be rejected.

The error suggests that EValType is not considered a supertype of either Literal type. I don't know that that means, though. (Bug in mypy?)

@chepner you're right! It does seem to work without the type hints in the implementation (implicit typing.Any). Do you have any explanation for that?
As for EValType not being a supertype of Literal, I thought the same. However, this does seem to be the correct way to use enums with overloads.

Interestingly, https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#literal-types-and-enums shows examples of things like reveal_type(EValType.STRING) producing Literal[EValType.STRING], but no examples of the Literal value being used as a type hint.

This has nothing to do with Literal... The problem is that T is not compatible with str, so the definition is not assignable to the first overload (same for the second). If you replace the typevar with union, the error goes away. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=1559efbb48e7c283133d5265dba1929d

@STerliakov I see! So there might be something I didn't quite understand in python generics... Thank you for your answer!
